# How can I test a function returning a struct in solidity using chai in hardhat

Tags: unit-testing, testing, solidity, chai, hardhat

**I have the following function** :

```
function getACountry(string memory _countryISO2Code)
    external
    view
    badCountryCode(_countryISO2Code)
    mustAlreadyExist(_countryISO2Code)
    returns (Country memory) //Country is a struc of a country in the contract...
  {
    string memory isoCode = Tools.toUpperCase(_countryISO2Code);
    return countriesMap[isoCode];
  }
```

I want to know the most efficient way to test this code(returning a struct) in hardhat using chai. Giving it a valid country ISO2Code, I want to test if it returning the right country information if the giving country is already stored in the contract... Thanks

Comment: Found this while looking for a solution to the same problem.  I ended up using the `toString` method on the JS Object returned to the test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the best way, but this one works for me. For example, your code could return a `struct` like this

```
struct Country {
  uint a;
  uint b;
  string c;
}
```

In your test, you can use:

```
expect(await contract.getACountry("FR")).to.have.member([1, 2, "FR"])
```

Or you can use an extension for chai (chai-subset) for a more complex `struct` (like `struct.struct.struct` or list of `struct`s).